# Firestore sub collection delete oldest in document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been struggling with figuring out how to delete documents from a sub collection, keep only the latest 5 documents.

I firstly try and get a list of documents in the sub collection, ordered by `'updated'` date timestamp. This however returns null

```
let updates = await firestore
    .collection('spots')
    .doc(spot.id)
    .collection('spotupdates')
    .orderBy('updated','desc');
```

I then try and delete the oldest from the list, to ensure only 5 remain

```
var cntr = 0;
while(updates.docs.length > 5){
    await firestore
        .collection('spots')
        .doc(spot.id)
        .collection('spotupdates')
        .doc(updates[cntr].id)
        .delete();
    cntr++;
}
cntr = null;
```

Please help - really stuck

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebase Documentation for deleting data from your database:

> To delete an entire collection or subcollection in Cloud Firestore,
>   retrieve all the documents within the collection or subcollection and
>   delete them. If you have larger collections, you may want to delete
>   the documents in smaller batches to avoid out-of-memory errors. Repeat
>   the process until you've deleted the entire collection or
>   subcollection.

You may find a **simplified code snippet** to delete collections and subcollections in **[this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections)**.

Also you will find more **information and detailed examples** about deleting fields, documents and collections in Firestore in **[this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections)**.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I've gone through all those before, but doesn't help in my current context. I'm not deleting an entire sub collection and im not concerned about limitations such as timeouts etc, as its likely to only ever have 6 documents in the collection. The orderby is the first issue where its returning nulls

Comment: @cfl Have you checked that the timestamp fields aren't actually null?

Comment: Some of them can be null, but most of them are set. According to the documentation, those that are null will just not be included in the filtered list, which is 100%. But the whole response is null

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar on my app but based on your data structure

First, get all the documents in the collection

```
const updates = await firestore
                 .collection('spots')
                 .doc(spot.id)
                 .collection('spotupdates')
                 .get()
```

Map the document data to return an array

```
const updatesArray = updates.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
```

Do logic then delete

```
if (updatesArray.length > 5){
            const sorted = updatesArray.sort((a,b) => b.created_at - a.created_at)
            const oldest = sorted.pop()
            await firestore
             .collection('spots')
             .doc(spot.id)
             .collection('spotupdates').doc(oldest.id).delete()
        }
```